# Google workspace reseller APIPOST https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/customers

Tags: google-admin-sdk

{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
"errors": [
{
"message": "Login Required.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"location": "Authorization",
"locationType": "header"
}
],
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
"domain": "googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"service": "reseller.googleapis.com",
"method": "ccc.hosted.frontend.v1.ResellerCustomers.Insert"
}
}
]
}
}

how to solve this error?